# GetModuleFileName in NASM x86 assembly

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

Here's the code...

```
extern GetStdHandle
extern GetModuleFileNameW
extern WriteFile
extern ExitProcess

import GetStdHandle kernel32.dll
import GetModuleFileNameW kernel32.dll
import WriteFile kernel32.dll
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll

global ..start

segment .code USE32

..start:

push dword -11
call [GetStdHandle]
mov dword [hStdOut], eax

;Getting the filepath of exe on disk...
push dword 256 ;MAX_PATH
push dword [filepath] ;Pointer to the buffer
push dword 0 ;NULL
call [GetModuleFileNameW]

;Trying to output the filepath...
push dword 0
push dword nBytes
push dword 256 ;MAX_PATH
push dword filepath
push dword [hStdOut]
call [WriteFile]

xor eax, eax
push eax
call [ExitProcess]

segment .data

segment .bss
hStdOut resd 1
nBytes resd 1
filepath resd 32
```

I've played around with it a bit, and all I get is a blank output. I've also gotten a bunch of gibberish when I play around with it a bit. Still no file path, and still no joy. I have a hunch that I'm doing something wrong with GetModuleFileNameW, but I can't be sure. I followed the documentation on the Microsoft website, and I put the arguments in in the opposite order like you're supposed to in assembly language. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This `push dword [filepath]` looks suspicious...

Answer (score 1):

```
;Getting the filepath of exe on disk...
push dword 256 ;MAX_PATH
push dword [filepath] ;Pointer to the buffer
push dword 0 ;NULL
call [GetModuleFileNameW]
```

... must be changed to...

```
;Getting the filepath of exe on disk...
push dword 256 ;MAX_PATH
push dword filepath ;Pointer to the buffer
push dword 0 ;NULL
call [GetModuleFileNameW]
```

Comment: Also note that `GetModuleFileNameW` handles the lengths (either the input and the returned one) in `TCHAR`s, that means that for the Unicode version the lengths are the number of WORDs (16 bits) allocated/copied. You are reserving 32 DWORD, i.e. 128 Bytes, that's room for only 64 unicode chars, not 256.

Comment: Update : I'm not using Unicode, I'm using GetModuleFileNameA, which is in ANSI characters. I did see that there appears to be spaces between characters when using GetModuleFileNameW, which is probably just the way it is in the Unicode format.